# Android Vertical and Horizontal Scrolling in OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: android, scroll, opengl-es-2.0

Can any one give me a example on how to add vertical and horizontal scroll till the end of the  GLSurfaceview which is zoomed. I have tried using Matrix.Translate and Matrix.Rotate with 0deg angle none of it works.

The ways i have used. In here dx and dy are the amount scrolled which i get from onTouch multiplied by a constant factor:

way 1:

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

```
mOffset = mPositionX + mPositionY;

// Draw background color
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Set the camera position (View matrix)
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, mOffset, mOffset, -3, mOffset, mOffset, 0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Calculate the projection and view transformation
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

mGraph.draw(mMVPMatrix);

mLine.draw(mMVPMatrix);
```

}

way 2:

@Override public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

```
mOffset = mPositionX + mPositionY;
Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, mSurfaceRatio * zoomFactor, -mSurfaceRatio * zoomFactor, -1 * (zoomFactor + mOffset), zoomFactor + mOffset, 3, 7);
// Draw background color
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Set the camera position (View matrix)
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Calculate the projection and view transformation
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

mGraph.draw(mMVPMatrix);

mLine.draw(mMVPMatrix);
```

}

way 3:

@Override public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

```
mOffset = mPositionX + mPositionY;
// Draw background color
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, 0, 0, mOffset, 0);

Matrix.multiplyMM(mProjMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

// Set the camera position (View matrix)
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Calculate the projection and view transformation
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

mGraph.draw(mMVPMatrix);

mLine.draw(mMVPMatrix);
```

}

Comment: Which matrices are you applying the operations on, and in what order are you doing the operations?

Comment: Thanks for the reply michael. I tried applying translate for both proj matrix and mVPMatrix. In the Rotation i created a new matrix and multiplied it with the mVPMatrix.

Comment: Hi deepe, i am also facing this problem in opengl es 2.0 in android. if you get any solution ,  please help me..

Comment: Hi Harikrisnan, I have answered the question in the answer for my problem go thru the link. Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns Out that the vertex shader in the Android OpenGL example is wrong. Its correct in the docs but if you download the example it has wrong shader code. As suggested by tim in the following link:

[Android OpenGL weirdness with the setLookAtM method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924020/android-opengl-weirdness-with-the-setlookatm-method)