# How can I draw two squares side by side?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Following the [android OpenGL ES tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html), I can draw a square to the screen.

I'd like to draw a second square to the screen, beside the initial square, so I've done as follows (only twice):

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 3.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0);
float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 2, 2, 0); //arbitrarily picking 2, the correctly drawn square uses 0's.
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0)
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0);
```

and then proceed to draw it ([link to google's code](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/OpenGLES.zip))

notably:

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
"attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
"void main() {" +
"  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
"}";
```

and

```
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
float ratio = (float) width / height;
Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
```

However, my second square is skewed like so:

[image]

Why is this the case?  How can I simply draw a square beside this one, without modifying the  initial coordinates?

My suspicion is it has something to do with Matrix.setLookAtM(), and that the projection is reshaping the square.  I'm not sure how to go about fixing this however!

Comment: The second `multiplyMM` looks wrong. The code's multiplying `VMP`, where it should be `PVM`; switch the arguments.

Comment: @StefanHanke I switched the second argument to: `Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);` but now I get a larger version of the same thing.  Any ideas? Are these the arguments you meant to switch?

Comment: Yes. Well, then try good old printf-debugging -- the MVP matrix for the shader, which data is actually sent etc. Is the Z-Buffer enabled?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread solved my issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924020/android-opengl-weirdness-with-the-setlookatm-method)

In the shader, I was multiplying by

```
vPosition * uMVPMatrix;"
```

but the multiplications should follow the ordering:

```
transformed vertex = projMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * input vertex
```

*note that input vertex comes after the projection, view and model matrix (MVPMatrix)*

So switching to

```
vPosition * uMVPMatrix;
```

and

```
float[] pvMatrix = new float[16];
//projection * view
Matrix.multiplyMM(pvMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix,0, mScale[0],mScale[1], 1.0f);
Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mPosition[0],mPosition[1], mPosition[2]);
//projection * view * model
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix,0, pvMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
```

Did the trick!