# OpenGL ES Android Matrix Transformations

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a renderer implementing GLSurfaceView.Renderer interface; a subclass of GLSurfaceView and some classes representing my objects I want to draw. I have the code from http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/motion.html
I want to expand this and add some moving along axes and can't manage it. The object is only rotated.
and here is my code:

```
public class NotMyCoolRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

public GLShip mTriangle;
private GLBackgroundStar   mSquare;

private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] tempMatrix = new float[16];

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    // Draw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
    // Draw square
    mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    // Now moving on to triangle aka ship
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.1f, 0f, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTriangle.mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(tempMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0); 
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix , 0, tempMatrix , 0);  

    // Draw triangle
    mTriangle.draw(mMVPMatrix);
}
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
    // such as screen rotation
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

}

public class GLShip {
    public volatile float mAngle;
    private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +

        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
        "}";


    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                     GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                     vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        NotMyCoolRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        NotMyCoolRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }
}
```

My expectations are that on each redrawing the object would be rotated by mAngle and traslated along Y-Axis by 1f. I can see only rotating (a bit projected too) though.
I actually got some questions regarding that: 
how do I apply my translation matrix and
what is the best practice of dividing the opengl functionality? Should not the modelMatrix be stored in the object itself rather than in renderer? Should the matrix operations be performed in the renderer-class?
I have grouped them together since I guess that they are all related.

Comment: Hmm. still nothing to explain how mProjMatrix is initialized.

Comment: Here's a final hint: try to replicate step by step the lessons from http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217 . It covers only javascript, but the differences are next to minimal. The API is the same and the matrix math is the same. Good luck!

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen In another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925647/is-googles-android-opengl-tutorial-teaching-incorrect-linear-algebra) people suggested (for the same code of the same tutorial) using `gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;` instead of `gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;`. If i follow the suggestion, i cant see my triangle at all

Comment: You should also calculate the MVP matrix in the order of M,V,P. You calculate it currently in order of P,V,M

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen this also does not solve the problem. I cant see my triangle with M*(V*P) at all

Comment: I have a note not related to your question. Please don't use `Matrix.rotateM()` in `onDrawFrame()` - it allocates extra 16 floats. Such memory allocation on each draw frame iteration has a significant impact on performance. Read my notes about this here: http://androidworks-kea.blogspot.com/2012/05/developers-notes-about-opengl-es.html and code samples here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b30dd2a437cfb076?pli=1

Comment: @keaukraine as mentioned in the question, I have taken the code from a google's tutorial, but thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I´ve been working with the example from the Android Training, the following approach finally works for me. (Based on [Android Training > Displaying Graphics with OpenGL ES > Adding Motion](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/motion.html))

1. Use the correct vertex shader:

   ```
   private final String vertexShaderCode =
   // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
   // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
   "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
   "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
   "void main() {" +
   // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
   "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
   "}";
   ```
2. In the renderer class:

   ```
   public class MyGL20Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
   [...]
   // create a model matrix for the triangle
   private final float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
   // create a temporary matrix for calculation purposes,
   // to avoid the same matrix on the right and left side of multiplyMM later
   // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480043/opengl-es-android-matrix-transformations#comment18443759_13480364
   private float[] mTempMatrix = new float[16];
   [...]
   ```
3. Apply transformations in *onDrawFrame*, start with *translation*:

   ```
   public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
   [...]
   Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0); // initialize to identity matrix
   Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -0.5f, 0, 0); // translation to the left
   ```
4. Then *rotation*:

   ```
   // Create a rotation transformation for the triangle
   long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
   float mAngle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
   Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);
   ```
5. Combine rotation and translation, **avoid using *mModelMatrix***

   > "as the same matrix on the right and left side of multiplyMM" (see [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480043/opengl-es-android-matrix-transformations#comment18443759_13480364))

   ```
   // Combine Rotation and Translation matrices 
   mTempMatrix = mModelMatrix.clone();
   Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
   ```
6. Combine the model matrix with the projection and camera view; **again avoid using *mModelMatrix***

   > "as the same matrix on the right and left side of multiplyMM" (see [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480043/opengl-es-android-matrix-transformations#comment18443759_13480364))

   ```
   // Combine the model matrix with the projection and camera view
   mTempMatrix = mMVPMatrix.clone();
   Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
   ```
7. Draw the shape

   ```
   // Draw shape
   mTriangle.draw(mMVPMatrix);
   ```

Thank you all, for all the useful input I could draw from this thread.

Comment: This works perfectly - the only tutorial I've come across which has helped me out. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: In case it helps anyone else who comes across this answer, the part that wasn't obvious to me was that Matrix.multiplyMM modifies the destination matrix _during_ calculation, not after.  So if you want to multiply mvp by rotation, and put the result in mvp, going Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0) will be mutating mMVPMatrix on the fly, resulting in a weird calculation.  This is why the clone above works.  

For my purposes, I was able to "chain" calculations by flipping between two different "scratch" matrixes, eg: http://pastebin.com/h7c9Ktg9

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see movement, you should update mTriangle.mAngle each frame (preferably as a function of time to combat speed differences or delays caused by other processes...).

Note that Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0); restores all the accumulated rotations and  translations to "zero" or actually to Identity Matrix... 
The same convention applies btw to all *set* functions.
To accumulate all the transformations, one has to

- setIdentity(model);
- translate(trans);  // to get the origin of rotation
- rotate(rotmatrix); // to accumulate the rotation
- translate(t2);     // to translate again to some better position...

Also one should keep the values of object translation vector [ox,oy,oz] between each call and feed them to Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, ox, oy, oz, 0);

Typically one concatenates all 'translate, rotate, scale', etc. matrices as early as possible and cache them per object, or hierarchically per a complex container having multiple objects and having a bounding box, so that multiple objects can be culled when on behind the camera (or generally outside the viewing frustum).

Also typically one keeps a moving camera in one matrix and per frame multiplies it with the projection matrix.

You can start with something like:

```
float Time = System.currentTimeMillis() * 0.01f;  // 10 radians / second == fast!
Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, Math.sin(Time)*2.0f, 0, 1f, 0);
...
```

As Tim noticed, there is no projection matrix involved, meaning that all z-values behave in this code exactly, even though changing x & y values would make a difference.

I'd be tempted to say, that MVP matrix would mean multiplying 
in order M * V * P = (M*V) * P = M * (V*P).

Comment: i forgot to mention that the drawing method is triggered by my EventListener, so i guess, i dont need the time function yet. My triangle rotates as expected. It just doesnt move along axes.

Comment: That's because there is this *setRotate* instead of Matrix.rotateM. (or whatever it is in Android GLES API)

Comment: I have now 
`Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);     
Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 1f, 0f, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTriangle.mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(tempMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, tempMatrix, 0);` and still see rotation around the Z-Axis only and no any other movement. Thanks for the tip with translating the objects to the origin. I will address this problem after i manage it to move the object off the origin.

Comment: I see no reason why the translation didn't work (unless your camera = mVMatrix follows the triangle...) What do you have for mProjMatrix?

Comment: i have updated my code sample in the question. Maybe you could take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're not applying your projection matrix to the triangle you're drawing, that could cause problems.

Should probably be:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);  
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVMatrix, 0);
```

Comment: should not the first line be `Matrix.multiplyMM(mVMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0)` ? If yes, I still can see rotation only. No translation.

Comment: AFAIK You can't have the same matrix on the right and left side of the multiplyMM: *However, the result element values are undefined if the result elements overlap either the lhs or rhs elements.*. I've defined a new matrix there, the 'ModelView' matrix, to hold the temporary result of the view*model multiplication.

Comment: did the same as you - defined a temporary matrix. Still same problem, as expected.